# Command prompt change after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-prompt

I changed my command prompt using `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "` but after reboot, it returns to be the default command prompt. How can I make this change to be permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "`

to the file `.bashrc` (assuming your shell is `bash`) in your home directory.

You can do this with:

`echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "'>>~/.bashrc`

Minor background: `PS1` is an *environment variable* - a variable that's set for your login session. `.bashrc` is a file that's read and interpreted by your shell every time it starts up, and you can use it to configure other attributes of the way your shell behaves.

For example, a common way to change your default editor is to add the line

`export EDITOR="emacs"`

to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Technically, `PS1` does not need to be an environment variable. Since it is only used by interactive shells, it needs only be set in that shell, and not inherited by child shells. Simply setting it (no `export` needed) is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "` to the .bashrc file in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ " to the .bashrc file in your home directory.

If the bashrc is not open.

Then set export EDITOR="vim".